# Length of a datetimeindex in python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta, datetimeindex

I just cant find the answer and I know pandas eats problems like this for desert.

I have a `datetime index` and want to know its length, in years:

```
idx=pd.date_range('2011-07-03', '2015-07-10')
```

expected output:

```
4.0191 years   (4 years and 7 days)
```

If I do:
`idx[0]-idx[-1]` I get an output in `days`, but id like it in years

Sorry: couldn't locate on `panads` docs

Comment: Is `4.0191` years really accurate? Years can vary in length, I'm not sure I see the usefulness of that value.

Comment: I have a return value. I need to annualise it by dividing by the number of years. 

my index is my datetime index. 

I just wanted its lenth in years to be my denominator. 

4.0191 years may not be the exact answer. I wrote it because I manually calculated it was 4 years, plus the 3rd july to 10th july days

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert timedelta to days and then divide by `365.25` if is not necessary `100%` accuracy:

```
idx=pd.date_range('2011-07-03', '2015-07-10')

print ((idx[-1]-idx[0]).days / 365.25)

4.0191649555099245
```

But if need `year`s with `day`s:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

r = relativedelta(idx[-1], idx[0])
print('{} years {} days'.format(r.years, r.days))
4 years 7 days
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess I thought perhaps there was something like
print ((idx[-1]-idx[0]).years)?

Comment: @JunaidMohammad - No, it is not implemented in python yet.

Comment: @JunaidMohammad - Or if need `4 years 7 days` added new solution.

Answer (score 2):

Using `ptp` and `np.timedelta64`:

```
>>> idx.to_series().ptp() / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
4.019247486259129
```

If you want it to be more specific (down to the days) and get the `Timedelta` object, just don't divide:

```
>>> idx.to_series().ptp()
Timedelta('1468 days 00:00:00')
```

If the `date_range` is always sorted, then using `to_series` with `ptp` adds unnecessary complexity, and you can use part of [@jezrael's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52095441/3483203)

```
>>> (idx[-1] - idx[0]) / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
4.019247486259129
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [relativedelta](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html) as follows:

```
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

relativedelta(idx[0], idx[-1]).years
```

Make sure that the later date is the first argument.